# Is there a way to read from a file and fill the message buff without using set_buff()?

Tags: c++, grpc

Using grpc to transfer file. 
The implementation I'm using now is:
1: read from file to a char string buff
2: use set_buff to make the message for grpc
I find that there may be a lot overhead because it copys the data twice.
So is that possible to read from file and dirctly save into the message buff for gprc? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mutable_buff` method to get access to the pointer of the variable and then use it to assign it to the memory where you have data loaded from the file, or even more straightforward you call `set_allocated_buff`.

```
std::string data;
// load file content to data variable
response.set_allocated_buff(&data);
```

More info here: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp-generated